# При помощи jquery вставить строку

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Есть таблица типа:

```
<table class="test" id="kwit_main"
<thead>...</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="str">...</tr>
<tr class="focus">...</tr>
<tr class="focus">...</tr>
<tr class="focus">...</tr>
<tr class="focus">...</tr>
<tr class="str">...</tr>
<tr class="focus">...</tr>
<tr class="focus">...</tr>
<tr class="focus">...</tr>
<tr class="focus">...</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Как после первого str вставить еще одну строку?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.str').first().after('<tr>...</tr>');
```

```js
$('.str').first().after('<tr><td>NEW</td></tr>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="str"><td>...</td></tr>
    <tr class="focus"><td>...</td></tr>
    <tr class="focus"><td>...</td></tr>
    <tr class="focus"><td>...</td></tr>
    <tr class="str"><td>...</td></tr>
    <tr class="focus"><td>...</td></tr>
    <tr class="focus"><td>...</td></tr>
    <tr class="focus"><td>...</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```